# Query to get data from 2 different tables is taking long time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have this query,

```
select Column1,Column2, etc..
from Db1.dbo.Tb1 b Where b.Id1 in (
    select distinct Column3 as Id1 from Db2.dbo.Tb2 s where s.Id2 <> ''
    union
    select distinct Column4 as Id1 from Db2.dbo.Tb2 s where s.Id2 <> ''
)
```

It's taking more then 10 minutes and still processing on a good spec database.

I can't change existing DB or add indexes, Is there anyway I could improve this query ?

It's getting data 2 columns from a table and then based on results getting data from another database's table.

Comment: Small improvement could be to use UNION ALL since it's faster than UNION. Also EXISTS could be faster than IN

Comment: Please edit the question and [add an execution plan](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/03/getting-help-with-a-slow-query/). It contains good information for troubleshooting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rewrite your query such a way:

```
SELECT Column1, 
       Column2,
       etc..
FROM Db1.dbo.Tb1 b
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT TOP (1) 1
        FROM Db2.dbo.Tb2 s
        WHERE s.Id2 <> ''
            AND b.Id1 IN (s.Column3, s.Column4)
    )
```